# Can't retrieve array sent through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my function that get's all the id's ad stores them in an array them it sends the array to the php page. Using google chrome network tool i can see the request which has the array in the header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#insert_articoli").click(function(){
        var id_articoli = [];
        $.each($("input[name='articoli']:checked"), function(){
            id_articoli.push($(this).val());
        });
                    $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "componi_prodotto.php",
                     data: {data : id_articoli },

                     success: function(){
                             alert("OK");
                     }
             });
    });
});
```

I can't find a way to retrieve this array from my php page. Please help.

Comment: can you post the php and html for this?

Comment: are you sure you are actually echo-ing anything in the PHP function?

Comment: you should really add your PHP code to the question

Comment: can you post php code for this ?

Comment: I've tried even just doing a simple var_dump($_POST["data"]); and it will give an error that data isn't initialized. I'll post the complete code tomorrow since it's getting late where I am.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're echoing something in your PHP, then you need to have something to return to, so set a variable in the success function:

```
success: function(response){ // whatever is echoed in PHP will be in 'response'
     console.log(response);
}
```

Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.